# Create responsive web page with CSS (need help about page width)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to create responsive web-page for four sizes of screen (320px, 640px, 980px and 1024px). So when I play around with site size all seems fine, all responsive, but when I make size larger than 1024px, I want to stop any resizing actions and make page look like it looks when size 1024px. I trying to find solution in Internet but I didn't. So can somebody help me? Thanks!

P.S. 
I found info about using `max-width` property, but it didnt help.
I am using `vw` units for size definition.

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried.

Comment: You could try adding another media query and with min-width:1024px

Comment: I have it working here with a min-width:1024px; at the end can copied the max end widths Css into it - https://jsfiddle.net/b1ysh92s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a specific width in px for the page when the width is more than 1024.
For example if you have a `.container {width:100%;}` under the 1024 size, you can add:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.container {
    width:1000px;
}}
```

When the screen is larger than 1024px your .container still width 1000px.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the viewport meta tag to control your layout.

This article will help you.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport